# Why does capturing by value in lambda work although object is deleted?

Tags: c++, lambda, capture

Why does this code work?

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using FilterContainer = std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>>;

FilterContainer filters; 

class Widget
{
    public:
    int divisor = 0;
    void addFilter() const;
    Widget(int a):divisor(a){}
};

void Widget::addFilter() const
{
    auto divisorCopy = divisor;
    
    filters.emplace_back(
        [=](int value)
        { return value % divisorCopy == 0; }
    );
}

void doSomeWork()
{
auto pw = std::make_unique<Widget>(5); 

pw->addFilter(); 

} 

int main() {
   
   doSomeWork();
  
   std::cout<< filters[0](10);

    return 0;
}
```

The object widget is deleted after doSomeWork(), so why is divisor still copied succesfully in divisorCopy? When the function in filters is executed, divisor should be non-existent.

Comment: You instructed the lambda to capture everything by copy with `[=]`, so I am not sure why it is surprising to you that it works.

Comment: usually when you copy a value then the copy stays intact no matter what happens to the initial value

Comment: `divisor` is copied into `divisorCopy` not after `doSomeWork()` but inside it (when `addFilter()` is executed). At this point, the widget still exists. Then, for the lambda, `divisorCopy` was copied by value so from this point, it does not matter anymore if the original one will be destroyed or not because the lambda got its own copy.

Comment: But the lambda added in addFilter should be executed at runtime, after doSomeWork(). doSomeWork() just puts the definition of this lambda function into the filters, it does not execute it, but it is executed after doSomeWork() is executed.

Comment: @LiviuDorobantu That doesn't matter though. The lambda has no connection to the `Widget` object. All it has is a copy of `divisorCopy` made at the time of the `addFilter` call.

Comment: OMG, now I see. Sorry and thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't capture the `Widget` object, you capture the local variable `divisorCopy` by value.

This of course creates a copy of the `divisorCopy` value, stored internally in the lambda object. This lambda-local copy is separate and distinct from the original `divisorCopy` variable.

When `addFilter` function returns, the lambda-local copy still lives on and can be used.

The destruction of the `Widget` object isn't related to what happens.

Comment: fwiw, capturing the `Widget` by value would work as well